# строковая функция strlen

Tags: php

```
$str = “0”;
if (!strlen($str)) echo “EMPTY</br>”;
else echo “NOT EMPTY”;
```

Выведет:NOT EMPTY 
Вопрос: Почему?

Answer (score 5):

Функция `strlen()` возвращает длину строки. В данном случае длина — один символ "0". Поэтому `!strlen($str)` ложно.

Answer (score 1):

Пошагово, специально для PHP-программистов.

1. `$str` имеет значение `"0"`. Это строка длиной в один символ.
2. `strlen` строки длиной в один символ возвращает значение `1` (число, не строка).
3. Применять логическое отрицание к числу — довольно неочевидное действие. Происходит приведение типов, в результате которого заключается, что `1` – это `true`, значит `!1` — это `false`.

Проверить:

```
$str = "0";
echo $str;
echo strlen($str);
echo !strlen($str);
echo !1;
echo !0;
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `strlen($str) == 1`, следовательно, `!strlen($str) == 0`. Условие `if (0)`, естественно, не будет выполняться.

Comment: вы не совсем правы, оператор ! приводит к логическому значению. !strlen($str) == 0, но не === 0, т.к. === false